# parent and child tables

Tags: mysql

I am sorry if this topic has already been brought up.

The requirement is this: I am creating a family tree system, I need to keep the details of a person which can be a parent and/or a child to other persons. For example personA is parent of personB, personB is parent of personC (personA->personB->personC). My version of mysql to the above requirement is

**person**

```
|id |person_name|
 1 | personA
 2 | personB
 3 | personC
```

**my_parent**

```
|id | person_id | parent|
1  |  3 |  2
2  |  2 |   1
```

But I don't feel right about this. Can any mysql guru please give me some better advise and also an sql statement to iterate through to retrieve the person hierarchy. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need two tables for this. Instead, it is usually done with a single table with a column for the parent that references another `person_id` in the same table:

#### Table `people`

```
person_id | person_name | parent_id
1         | JSmith Jr   | 2
2         | JSmith Sr   | 3
3         | Grandpa     | NULL
```

To query it, you use JOIN against itself:

```
SELECT 
  child.person_name AS childname,
  child.person_id,
  parent.person_name AS parentname
FROM 
  /* First use of the table for the child */
  people AS child
  /* JOIN against the same table to get the parent's name */
  /* LEFT JOIN is used in case the parent_id is NULL and the parent is unknown */
  LEFT JOIN people AS parent ON child.parent_id = parent.person_id
```

Produces:

```
childname  | id | parentname
-----------|----|-------------
JSmith Jr  | 1  | JSmith Sr
JSmith Sr  | 2  | Grandpa
Grandpa    | 3  | NULL
```

#### Update To allow for multiple parents, use 2 tables:

Table `people`:

```
person_id | person_name
1         | JSmith Jr
2         | JSmith Sr
3         | Grandpa
4         | Grandma
5         | MomSmith
```

Table `relationships`:

```
person_id | parent_id | relationship
1         | 2         | father
1         | 5         | mother
2         | 3         | father
2         | 4         | mother
```

To query for mother & father:

```
SELECT
  child.person_id,
  child.person_name AS childname,
  mother.person_name AS mothername,
  father.person_name AS fathername
FROM 
  people AS child
  JOIN relationships AS rc ON child.person_id = rc.person_id
  LEFT JOIN people AS mother ON rc.parent_id = mother.person_id AND relationship = 'mother'
  LEFT JOIN people AS father ON rc.parent_id = father.person_id AND relationship = 'father'
```

Untested, but should produce:

```
person_id | childname | mothername | fathername
1         | JSmith Jr | MomSmith   | JSmith Sr
2         | JSmith Sr | Grandma    | Grandpa
3         | Grandpa   | NULL       | NULL
4         | Grandma   | NULL       | NULL
5         | MomSmith  | NULL       | NULL
```

Comment: It is better to use a relation table, because one person can have more than one parents.

Comment: @xdazz Yes that's probably true in this case. I missed the plural 'child of other persons' in the requirement.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your quick relying, I didn't know a table can be joined to itself, I've leaned new thing today.

Comment: @xdazz can you please give me an example of how you would do it, thanks

Comment: @user1152967 See additions above -  I added a method for querying multiple parents from two tables.

Comment: I use of composite key is a better option to the 3 `ids` in one table. I believe the relation for multiple parents is pefect. +1